# JQuery Datepicker only showing when no jquery stylesheet included

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I have datepicker configured to use on my page.. and if I don't add a jquery theme, the datepicker shows..

Problem is that when I add a jquery theme ( such as ui-lightness), the datepicker doesn't show anymore. I can see in firebug that the datepicker is there, but it doesn't show!!

I use `$this->Jquery()->addStylesheet('path');` to add the stylesheet and when I check browser source code, the stylesheet is present..

I already removed all other css to check if it was an interference issue, but without luck.

help?

Question expanded:

working in a cms from the book Apress Pro Zend Framework Techniques - build full CMS.

Datepicker is initialized through following files :

bootstrap.php

```
$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");
```

layout.phtml

```
echo $this->jQuery();
```

With only these commands I get a full working datepicker, only in a very basic layout.
When I add a stylesheet through:

layout.phtml

```
$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('js/jQuery/css/ui-darkness/jquery-i-1.8.9.custom.css') echo $this->headLink();
```

The datepicker is still on the page, but no longer visible.
I tried reffering to the custom jquery.ui js in layout.phtml through

```
$this->headScript()->appendFile('js/jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js'); echo $this->headScript();
```

but with no result... in both cases the css and js files are there in source code. so no broken links.  I commented out all css-links, so I'm sure there's no interference.

---

Question expanded:

working in a cms from the book Apress Pro Zend Framework Techniques - build full CMS.

Datepicker is initialized through following files :

bootstrap.php

$view->addHelperPath("ZendX/JQuery/View/Helper", "ZendX_JQuery_View_Helper");

layout.phtml

echo $this->jQuery();

with only these commands I get a full working datepicker, only in a very basic layout.

When I add a stylesheet through:

layout.phtml

$this->headLink()->prependStylesheet('js/jQuery/css/ui-darkness/jquery-i-1.8.9.custom.css')
echo $this->headLink();

the datepicker is still on the page, but no longer visible.

I tried reffering to the custom jquery.ui js in layout.phtml through

$this->headScript()->appendFile('js/jQuery/js/jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js');
echo $this->headScript();

but with no result..

in both cases the css and js files are there in source code. so no broken links.

I commented out all css-links, so I'm sure there's no interference.

Comment: What happens if you add the stylesheet statically, i.e. using a Link tag?

Comment: same thing.. stylesheet is there..

Comment: funny thing is that when I use the jquery.ui.datepicker.css stylesheet.. it does change the layout of the datepicker, but when I import the jquery.ui.all.css sheet, datepicker is no longer visible.. so my best guess is a z-index or display problem..

Comment: could you please expand your question? How do you initialize the datepicker?

Comment: question expanded below.. thx fr helping me figure this out!

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me today.  I think it was because I use an older version of jquery-ui (distributed with Ubuntu).  Choosing the "Legacy release" option before clicking my custom theme's download link produced CSS that made the datepicker work again.

Side note:  The versions of jquery and jquery-ui that I'm using, while not the latest, are newer than those listed as current on the custom theme download page.  I'm a little surprised that I have to use the "legacy" option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all download your theme form this link http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Reference the css and the js in your web site and the calendar will be visible.

If you want to add your own calendarImage and avoid the three dots {...} use the buttonImage: property in the initialization of the calendar

```
$("#Element").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'M d, yy',
        navigationAsDateFormat: true, prevText: 'M', nextText: 'M',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        showOn: "both",
        showStatus: true,
        firstDay: 0,
        buttonImage: '/Content/images/Calendar_img.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true
  });
```

Have also a look at this [Zend Framework - JQuery - Date Picker - Format Date to YYYY-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251673/zend-framework-jquery-date-picker-format-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd) and this [Zend Framework - JQuery - Date Picker - Images not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2243936/zend-framework-jquery-date-picker-images-not-displayed)

Hope it helps

Comment: downloaded from themeroller.. both css and js files are linked. ( being jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.css and jquery-ui-1.8.9.custom.min.js ). but no